# Cannot find control with name when using with form recursively

Tags: angular, forms, recursion

I'm recursively creating a form but I'm getting a cannot find control with name error. You can see how I use in it in the stackblitz but the from is uncommented for me. In my opinion it seems like the form isn't being loaded for some reason because if I delete the insides of the form I get the same exact errors.

```html
    <form [formGroup]="transactionOrRefundRequestForm" class="request-form">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="formEntryTemplate; context: {$implicit: formStructure}">
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #formEntryTemplate let-childEntries>
      <ng-container class="container" *ngFor="let formEntry of childEntries">
        <ng-container *ngIf="isCategory(formEntry)">
          <div formGroupName="{{toCategory(formEntry).name}}" class="category"> <----This is the issue -->
            <table class="header">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span>{{toCategory(formEntry).name}}</span>
                </td>
                <td class="form-buttons">
                  <button color="primary" (click)="addInput(formEntry)" mat-raised-button>Add Field</button>
                  <button color="primary" (click)="addCategory(formEntry)" mat-raised-button>Add Category</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
            <ng-container  *ngTemplateOutlet="formEntryTemplate; context{$implicit:toCategory(formEntry).entries}">
            </ng-container>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
        <tr class="input" *ngIf="isInput(formEntry)">
          <td>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="full-width">
              <mat-label>{{toInput(formEntry).name}}</mat-label>
              <input formControlName="{{toInput(formEntry).name}}" matInput>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="input" *ngIf="isSelect(formEntry)">
          <td>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="full-width">
              <mat-label>{{toSelect(formEntry).name}}</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="{{toSelect(formEntry).name}}">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let value of formEntry.values" [value]="value">{{value}}</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="input" *ngIf="isBoolean(formEntry)">
          <td>
            <mat-label>{{toBoolean(formEntry).name}}</mat-label>
            <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="{{toBoolean(formEntry).name}}"></mat-slide-toggle>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
  </form>
```

This forms is at the top of the class it's the first thing set.

```
public transactionOrRefundRequestForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
i: new FormGroup({
  i: new FormGroup({
    MessageType: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    MessageClass: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    MessageCategory: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    SaleID: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    POIID: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    ProtocolVersion: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    ServiceID: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/), Validators.maxLength(10)]),
  }),
  PaymentRequest: new FormGroup({
    i: new FormGroup({
      i: new FormGroup({
        TransactionID: new FormControl(''),
        TimeStamp: new FormControl('')
      })
    }),
    PaymentTransaction: new FormGroup({
      i: new FormGroup({
        Currency: new FormControl(''),
        RequestedAmount: new FormControl('')
      }),
      ProprietaryTags: new FormGroup({
        PrintReceipt: new FormControl('')
      })
    }),
    PaymentData: new FormGroup({
      PaymentType: new FormControl('')
    })
  }),
})
 });
```

Comment: Here is a stackbltiz for it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nqndkq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this question is the same as for this one:

[Angular NgModel Binding cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64268137/angular-ngmodel-binding-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Here is the solution:

The problem was in my html, when using ng-container the forms started to get funky.
Now when I generate the my html recursively this soltuion works:

```
<ng-template #formCategoryTemplate let-formCategory>
   <div [formGroup]="getFormGroup(formCategory)" class="request-form">
     </ng-container>
       <tr class="input" *ngIf="isInput(formEntry)">
         <td>
           <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="full-width">
             <input [formControl]="getFormControl(toInput(formEntry))" matInput>
           </mat-form-field>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </ng-container>
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

The toIput will just take the entry and `return entry as InputEntry`

The getFormGroup will just `return myFormGroup`